# can't sending smtp emails with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

my codeigniter framework wont send emails by smtp. I always return a error that he cannot send the my by smtp over php on this server. If i check my username, host and password by copy and past to login with a webclient into the mailbox, it workds. So i use the correct host, username and password.

I think i have setup something wrong, but i dont know what.

Thats the email_helper

```
$config['mailpath']             = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"

        $config['protocol']             = "smtp";

        $config['smtp_host']            = $settings['smtp_host']; (smtp.domain.com)

        $config['smtp_port']            = $settings['smtp_port']; (465)

        $config['smtp_timeout']         = '30';

        $config['smtp_user']            = $settings['smtp_user']; (email = user)

        $config['smtp_pass']            = $settings['smtp_pass']; (my password)

        $config['mailtype']             = 'html';

        $config['charset']              = 'utf-8';

        $config['newline']              = "\r\n";

        $config['wordwrap']             = TRUE;

        $controller->load->library('email');

        $controller->email->initialize($config);   

        $controller->email->from( $settings['email_from'] , $settings['application_name'] );

        $controller->email->to($to);

        $controller->email->subject($subject);

        $controller->email->message($body);

        if($cc != '') 
        {   
            $controller->email->cc($cc);
        }   

        if($attachment != '')
        {

            $controller->email->attach(base_url()."your_file_path/" .$attachment);

        }

        if($controller->email->send()){

            return "success";

        }
        else
        {
            echo $controller->email->print_debugger();
        }
    }
```

I've chekced the correct values from the $settings array, too.

To send the email i do it in this way
$this->mailer->mail_template($to,'forget-password',$mail_data);

Answer (score 0):

Adding the ssl information solved the problem

```
$config['smtp_crypto']          = 'ssl';
```